# Enforce reduced logging from certain logging sources for Python/PySpark applications

Tags: python, apache-spark, logging, log4j

I'm running a Spark application for which I want to have INFO level logging.

However, along with my application logs, it seems like other loggers are producing massive amounts of output on the INFO level, drowning out the useful information I'm trying to log. Example:

```
[/var/log/yarn/userlogs/application_1683930949263_0001/container_1683930949263_0001_01_000009/stderr] 2023-05-13 00:10:40,556 INFO executor.Executor: Finished task 389.0 in stage 1043.0 (TID 146334). 3284 bytes result sent to driver
[/var/log/yarn/userlogs/application_1683930949263_0001/container_1683930949263_0001_01_000009/stderr] 2023-05-13 00:10:40,556 INFO storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Getting 0 (0.0 B) non-empty blocks including 0 (0.0 B) local and 0 (0.0 B) host-local and 0 (0.0 B) remote blocks
[/var/log/yarn/userlogs/application_1683930949263_0001/container_1683930949263_0001_01_000009/stderr] 2023-05-13 00:10:40,556 INFO storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator: Started 0 remote fetches in 0 ms
[/var/log/yarn/userlogs/application_1683930949263_0001/container_1683930949263_0001_01_000009/stderr] 2023-05-13 00:10:40,556 INFO mapred.SparkHadoopMapRedUtil: No need to commit output of task because needsTaskCommit=false: attempt_202305130010406528291275413594211_1043_m_000243_146190
[/var/log/yarn/userlogs/application_1683930949263_0001/container_1683930949263_0001_01_000009/stderr] 2023-05-13 00:10:40,557 INFO executor.Executor: Finished task 243.0 in stage 1043.0 (TID 146190). 3284 bytes result sent to driver
```

Is there an easy way to filter the logs *not* coming from my application logger (assuming I can figure out which one it is) so that only the logs I create are produced?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure logging by setting the level of your top-level logger to `INFO` and adding whichever handlers you're using to that logger, but not adding any handlers to the root logger, which by default will have a level of `WARNING`. (If you have multiple top-level modules, do this for all of them.)

If any of the libraries you use misbehave (e.g. by adding their own handlers to the root logger), you'll have to take a different approach - e.g. adding a filter to all handlers that drops any event which is not from your own code (based on the logger name).

Comment: Is there a good way to get all handlers if I'm not certain which one are present? Like a list that has all of them that I can access by index?